# How to protect client data on the cloud from the developers and the deployment team?

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, architecture, software-design

I am developing a medical software for a doctor whose primary concern is his data privacy.
He wants that the developers for the software and the vendor managing the deployment of the software on the cloud should not be able to view his data in the database in any instance.

I am planning to develop his software and deploying it on the google-cloud-platform.

Which methods can I follow while developing the backend app to ensure this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand - your question is very general.

In that case it may be useful to check the PDF file -  [Google Cloud security foundations guide](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/google-cloud-security-foundations-guide.pdf)

Another interesting document relevant to the healthcare domain - [Setting up a HIPAA-aligned project](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/setting-up-a-hipaa-aligned-project)